# Invisible dialog box fonts on Ubuntu Artful

Tags: display, fonts

I update Ubuntu 17.10 Artful and run into a issue with dialog box not very visible.

[image]

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Are you referring to the garbled text in the dark box with white text? Sorry it's not very clear what you're asking. If it's the garbled text, looks like a font issue to me.